# Spinner with items from different acitivity

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-spinner

I'm trying on my application to make a spinner with the data that is on one of my activity as a list for the spinner but i dont have any idea how to do that because it's my first time writing in kotlin.

Any idea? Thank you anticipated!

I tried making a list first with the items from the activity but it results that the list Will be created every time i press on the activity instead of updating it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.